# Knockout dirty flag event

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've used the Dirty Flag Blog post here [Knockmeout](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html) to implement such a flag in my model, but i can not get this to work properly. Somehow the flag is never set to true.

Additionaly i want my subscribe event to be triggered every time the dirty flag is set to true. (i'll to the reset manually).

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mike1/xw76d/2/) that shows my issue.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of small things:

- when you use `span` tags they should not be self-closing (so do `<span></span>`).  This was preventing your final binding from being shown.
- if you create your view model inside of an object literal, then `this` does not yet refer to the view model, so when you created your dirty flag it was not properly tracking your Filter object.  If you want to do an object literal, then you would want to create your dirty flag afterwards.
- the value binding when used with a select will populate your model value with a string.   So, I changed your `1` to `'1'`, otherwise it would be dirty immediately.  There is a way to force it to be numeric using a writeable computed observable.  Here is one [technique](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html#live_example_1_forcing_input_to_be_numeric).

Here is an updated sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/xw76d/4/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfect.